# inheritance in Sharepoint team site to subsite

Tags: sharepoint-designer, branding, template, inheritance

I would like to know if I am creating a subsite from a team site how I can edit the template to inherit the branding I apply to new subsites.

Is this possible and which template(s) do I edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reset the subsites to inherit the master page of the parent site in the masterpage option located under Settings -> Site Settings -> Look and Feel -> Master Page.

[image]

[image]

This option is disabled by default in the Team Sites to activate it you have first to activate the SharePoint Publishing features.

Note: The Team Sites in the SharePoint 2013 inherit the masterpage from the system sites.

Comment: Activating Publishing Features on Team site can have some negative impacts. Some of those features can't be deactivated adter you activated the.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript in a content editor webpart in the teamsite that checks the master page and sets it if it's not inheriting. Then, save the team site template. In the site collection settings, under page layouts and site templates, hide the default team site template and make the new one available. Detailed info is provided here http://dcsharepointchick.blogspot.com/2018/03/sharepoint-teamsite-branding-and-master.html